# MSbuild : error MSB6006: "VCBuild.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, msbuild

I was trying to locally install npm for one of my Github projects. I came across this error? Has anyone got a solution?

Also Because of that, Im getting this error too.

> 2784 verbose stack Error: node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: node scripts/build.js
>   2784 verbose stack Exit status 1
>   2784 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
>   2784 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
>   2784 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>   2784 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
>   2784 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
>   2784 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
>   2785 verbose pkgid node-sass@3.13.1
>   2786 verbose cwd D:\move-rewards-flows-master
>   2787 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   2788 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   2789 verbose node v9.2.0
>   2790 verbose npm  v5.5.1
>   2791 error code ELIFECYCLE
>   2792 error errno 1
>   2793 error node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: node scripts/build.js
>   2793 error Exit status 1
>   2794 error Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
>   2794 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   2795 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: I just upgraded my node from 6 to 8 and now am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my issue.

I had upgraded my node from 6 to 8 (stable). And my current project was not compiling. I remove my node module folders and use "npm install" to install them again.[image]

I know you have downloaded the project from github. Might be the issue with node-sass version. Your version seems lower and might not be compatible with latest version of nodejs.